# Can't find the syntax error in the sql Query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

```
String sql = "select date, Order_No, Round(sub_total,2) as Subtotal,"
                + "Round(Service_Tax,2) as Service_Tax, Round(VAT,2) as VAT, Round(KKC,2) as KKC_Tax,"
                + "Round(SBC,2) as SBC_Tax, Round(lux_tax,2) as Luxury_tax, Round(Total,2) as Total from Canteen"
                + "where Date between ? and ? order by date asc ";
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, date1.getText());
pst.setString(2, date2.getText());
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

date 1 and date 2 are two text fields. This query runs on button click action . Here I am getting error saying syntax error near the keyword " between ". This might be a silly mistake but i can't find what it is. Please help.

Comment: What is the actual text in date1 and date2?  it needs to be a date in SQL format.

Comment: text fields have date in the format " yyyyy-MM-dd " @SteveSmith

Comment: Please add a space between Canteen and where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo in final sql. Change `"where Dat` to `" where Dat`

Comment: Thanks... It was a silly mistake as i had anticipated